# How to get Microsoft Domain GUID from typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, typescript, windows-authentication

I need to implement domain login as a web application authentication.

One way is to provide a domain GUID to the API.

If this is not possible, is there any way to invoke the domain login window and provide the data to the API?

Comment: From what? A web browser? This is highly unlikely.

Comment: @tadman Yes, web browser.

Comment: Web browsers are generally unable to access operating system functions. This is done by design to ensure JavaScript code is safe and can't mess with your computer.